# Replacing JSON object with a called function from a database

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, xml

I try to convert my object into XML. But I don't want to write the JSON object like that, because I have a model in the server (Node.js) and this model has its own CRUD. I want to read my data after saving it and put it in this code to get my data convert it.

```
const o2x = require('object-to-xml');

const obj = { 
'?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?' : null,
 request : {
'@' : {
  type : 'product',
  id : 12344556
   },
  '#' : {
    query : {
    vendor : 'redhat',
    name : 'linux'
    }
    }
    },


    };

   console.log(o2x(obj));
```

This is my model:

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose')

   var Document_header = mongoose.model('Document_header',
   {
   Type_of_change:{type:String},
   OpData_identifier:{type:Number},
    Internal_Reference_Id:{type:Number},
   VPMN:{type:String},
   Sender:{type:String},
     File_Type:{type:String},
     OpData_Schema_version:{type:Number},
     Tadig_generic_shema:{type:String}

      },'document_header')

     module.exports = {Document_header}
    and this is my controller
    const express = require('express')
    var router = express.Router()
    var ObjectID = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId


   var { Document_header} = require('../models/document_header')


     router.get('/', (req, res) => {
     Document_header.find((err, docs) => {
    if (!err) res.send(docs)
    else console.log('Error while retrieving all records : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 
     2))
          })
       })

    router.post('/', (req, res) => {
      var newRecordd = new Document_header({

    Type_of_change:req.body.Type_of_change,
    OpData_identifier:req.body.OpData_identifier,
    Internal_Reference_Id:req.body.Internal_Reference_Id,
    VPMN:req.body.VPMN,
    Sender:req.body.Sender,
    File_Type:req.body.File_Type,
    OpData_Schema_version:req.body.OpData_Schema_version,
    Tadig_generic_shema:req.body.Tadig_generic_shema,
    
       })

     newRecordd.save((err, docs) => {
    if (!err) res.send(docs)
    else console.log('Error while creating new record : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2))
      })
     })

    router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send('No record with given id : ' + req.params.id)

      var updatedRecordd = {
  
    Type_of_change:req.body.Type_of_change,
    OpData_identifier:req.body.OpData_identifier,
    Internal_Reference_Id:req.body.Internal_Reference_Id,
    VPMN:req.body.VPMN,
    Sender:req.body.Sender,
    File_Type:req.body.File_Type,
    OpData_Schema_version:req.body.OpData_Schema_version,
    Tadig_generic_shema:req.body.Tadig_generic_shema,
       }

     Document_header.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: updatedRecordd },{new:true}, 
    (err, 
    docs) => {
    if (!err) res.send(docs)
    else console.log('Error while updating a record : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2))
     })
     })

   router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
     if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send('No record with given id : ' + req.params.id)

    Document_header.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, docs) => {
    if (!err) res.send(docs)
    else console.log('Error while deleting a record : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2))
      })
      })


   module.exports = router
```

I used the method find in the function to find my data, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Some servers will return response only in JSON, others will return only in XML, and some will return either but requires the request to add a parameter to select which type of response is expected.  Without know the server you are using I do not know if your server has an option of the type to return.

Comment: im using node js

Comment: The server is CRUD.  So it depends on what the server is capable of returning.  If server can only return XML then you must parse XML and not JSON.